# Platform specific xaml that is throwing error for the UWP platform

Tags: uwp, uno-platform

I have platform specific xaml that is throwing error for the UWP platform.

```
Unexpected 'NONE' in parse rule 'Element ::= . EmptyElement | ( StartElement ElementBody ).'.
```

My Xaml looks like:

```
xmlns:wasm="http://uno.ui/wasm" 
xmlns:not_wasm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"    
mc:Ignorable="d wasm not_wasm"
```

and

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <not_wasm:ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"  MaximumRowsOrColumns="8"/>
    <wasm:WrapPanel/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

The above builds without an error for wasm but for UWP it fails with the above error.
Any thoughts on what causes it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that your markup has the `not_wasm` namespace in the Ignorable list. So Windows ignores it, then thinks the `<ItemsPanelTemplate />` is empty.

In general, any platform-specific namespace that has "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" should *not* go in the Ignorable list.  Any platform-specific namespace of the form "http://uno.ui/xxxx" should go in the Ignorable list.

The correct markup would be:

```xml
xmlns:wasm="http://uno.ui/wasm" 
xmlns:not_wasm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"    
mc:Ignorable="d wasm"
```

and

```xml
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <not_wasm:ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"  MaximumRowsOrColumns="8"/>
    <wasm:WrapPanel/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Comment: As https://platform.uno/docs/articles/platform-specific-xaml.html says, For prefixes which will be excluded on Windows (e.g. android, ios), the actual namespace is arbitrary, since the Uno parser ignores it. The prefix should be put in the mc:Ignorable list. For prefixes which will be included on Windows (e.g. win, not_android) the namespace should be http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation and the prefix should not be put in the mc:Ignorable list.